# datepicker added dynamically won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have detected a problem with `datepicker`. I'm adding controls dinamically, and one of them is a datepicker, along side a couple of selects and a textarea.

Well, whenever i add a datepicker, lets say i have 3 `datepickers`, i set the date of the first, then i try to set the date of either the second or third, well, my problem is that setting the date of the second or third sets it to the first one

Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72UG/) to see the problem reproduced. Just add 2 or 3 datepicker clicking the add button and try to set the dates. Any idea on why is this and how can it be solved will be pretty much appreciated

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using the same ID when you clone the element, if you are using the same ID there is no way for the JavaScript to differentiate between them.

If you switch the IDs to classes it will work, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/j72UG/2/

HTML

```
<input type='button' value="add" id="addLi" />
<ul class="list">
    <li class="dateLi">
        <input type='text' class='date' />
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var liClone;

$(function () {
    liClone = $(".dateLi").clone(true);
    $(".dateLi").remove();
    $("#addLi").click(function () {
        var clonado = liClone.clone(true);
        clonado.appendTo(".list");
        clonado.find("input").datepicker();
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah, after a couple of hours playing with this, found out that the id's where the same and this was giving me the issue. I added a counter to the id, but this solutions seems better, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you're cloning, all your elements retain the same ID. In a given DOM structure, only one (1) element can have a specific ID at any given time. So give your list items a class or an ID ending with a serial instead, in order to avoid this problem in the future.

```
var li = $('<li class="dateLi"><input type="text" /></li>');
```

See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j72UG/3/).

Answer (score 1):

that's because you have to change the id of each input and li.
try this:

```
jsfiddle.net/LgRR7/
```